# An unknown error occured please check HTTP result code and inner exception for server response

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

This picture is of the upload fragment made by me using android studio and when the list item is been clicked the object should be downloaded.It's Working fine and the object is been downloaded on my phone and the other phone on which I installed it. But when I shared this application to others it gives the error marked in the picture on their phones.Updating the play services is not removing the error.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 2 days of frustration, I found out that there is a bug in firebase storage.Thus, you've to simply turn off and on your storage manually,thanks.

Comment: what do you mean? How to do that? I have the same problem here.

Comment: Go to settings>app permissions> if your storage permission is on then turn it off and on again it'll work

Comment: unbelievable.. my problem just fixed because I wrong on passing download path location parameters to FirebaseStorage.

Comment: @ayushsrivastava how to turn on and off storage permission. i don't get it

Comment: in your app permission settings you can change permission for storage

Answer (score 2):

May be this is the wrong path bug but in my case resolve this here is the example

i use this code then i received  error

```
public static StorageReference getChildProfileStorage(String vid){
    StorageReference storageReference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    storageReference.child("ParentDataStore").child(CurrentUser.getInstance().getEmail())
            .child("ChildDataStore").child(vid);


    return storageReference;
}
```

**here is the line that solve my problem**

```
public static StorageReference getStudentProfileStorage(String vid){
    StorageReference storageReference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("ParentDataStore")
            .child("StudentDataStore").child(vid).child("profile");
    return storageReference;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am late. but today I am also facing the same issue. What I've done is to update the storage library in build.Gradle (app) file. and it solved my problem.
Basically when you configure storage using Android studio firebase assistant. This will import the older version of the app. So don't to update a newer version

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was providing invalid system file path while calling [`getFile()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#public-filedownloadtask-getfile-file-destinationfile) of the [`FileDownloadTask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask), I was initially trying to download a file from Firebase.

Here the issued is raised as the downloadDirectory was invalid

```
File localFile = ...;
FileDownloadTask downloadTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                               .getReference()
                                               .child("fileName")
                                               .getFile(localFile);
```

Here the path of the `localFile` I was providing was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

After 3-4 hrs depression,i got the actual reason.
While downloading,I need to give storage permission of writing but I only gave read permission. In lower androids , read-write permission is same.Basically I was used to/accustomed to these lower version devices that's why forget to add write storage permission for the upper androids

Comment: in addition,when you ask/give permission programmactically,read-write are separate in higher android versions,but same when you give permission manually

Comment: please modify your answer to be more readable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and when I checked the Storage rules:

```
allow read, write: if false
```

I saw it was.

**It worked when I changed it to:**

```
allow read, write: if true
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated the implementation in the `build.gradle(:app)` to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
```